# How to check if a .dat file is present in a folder in python and if it is there,how to match it with associated csv?

Tags: python, filepath

I have a folder where I am getting `.dat` files whenever a `.csv` file is uploaded.

So, I want to check if a `.dat` file is present in a particular location and if it is there, only then do I want to upload my file to s3 using python and boto3.

Can anybody help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import os

path_to_your_file = ''
if os.path.isfile(path_to_your_file):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print("File doesn't exist")
```

Comment: I want to check if a specific pattern files is present in a location or folder,only then I want to start my upload to S3 process.

Comment: Actually I have test.dat file and test.csv file in a folder and I want to check if .dat file is present only then csv file should be uploaded to S3.

Comment: So, doesn't the checking with `os.path.isfile` help you?

Comment: Yes it will help,but the scenario is I have a folder where there are three .dat files-e.g-v1.dat, v2.dat and v3.dat and six csv files.g-v1.csv, v2.csv,v3.csv,v4.csv,v5.csv and v6.csv..To upload a csv file to s3 I have to first check whether .dat file is present in a folder.Then second step is to match the .dat with the associated csv e.g-v1.csv can be uploaded only when v1.dat is present.So,if u can answer based on this scenario,then it will help

Comment: Please, edit your question to make it focused on your specif problem, then I'll edit my answer to match it.

Comment: I have already specified the scenario in my last comment.As u advised,I have edited my question